# Attempting to make a Timeout for a google script UI alert

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timeout, alert

I am trying to figure out if I can Auto-Magically select no in a UI alert in google script..

```
var old = e.oldValue;
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi() ;
if( old == null ){} else{ 
if( old == "NO"){} else {
if(e.range.getRow() == 3 ) {} 
else{ var response = ui.alert('⚠️ Change order? ⚠️', 'Are you sure you want to change this order?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO)}}} ;
if(response == ui.Button.NO) {e.range.setValue(old)} ;
```

this is where I am at, everything works great.... as long as a button is pressed, I am hoping there is a way to Auto press "no" after ~20 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to automatically run the script as clicking "NO" button after 20 seconds from opening the dialog.

### Modification points:

- Unfortunately, in the current stage, the count down cannot be achieved with `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert()`. So in your situation, in order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose to use the custom dialog. When the custom dialog is used, Javascript can be used. By this, the count down can be used.

When above points are reflected to a script, it becomes as follows.

### Sample script:

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please copy and paste the following script to `Code.gs` of the script editor of Spreadsheet.

```
function processForNo(value) {
  // do something
  Browser.msgBox(`Clicked NO. Retrueved value is '${value || ""}'.`);
}

function processForYes(value) {
  // do something
  Browser.msgBox(`Clicked YES. Retrueved value is '${value || ""}'.`);
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  var value = "ok";
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
  html.value = value;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate().setHeight(100), '⚠️ Change order? ⚠️');
}
```

#### HTML & Javascript:

Please copy and paste the following script to `index.html` of the script editor of Spreadsheet.

```
Are you sure you want to change this order?
<input type="button" id="yes" value="YES" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).processForYes()">
<input type="button" id="no" value="NO" onclick="processForNo('')">
<script>
const processForNo = _ => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).processForNo(<?= value ?>);
setTimeout(processForNo, 20000);
</script>
```

- When `main()` of above script is run, a dialog is opened. When you don't click the buttons, the dialog is closed after 20 seconds, and the process is run as clicking "NO" button. At that time, `processForNo` is run. Also, the value can be sent when the dialog is opened.
- When "YES" button is clicked, `processForYes` is run.

#### Testing:

When above script is tested, the following situation is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- Above script is a sample script for confirming the script. When above script is included in your script, it becomes as follows.

  - Google Apps Script side

    ```
      function myFunction() {

        // do something. I cannot understand about your whole script. So please add your actual script and function name.

        var old = e.oldValue;
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        if (old == null) {
        } else {
          if (old == "NO") {
          } else {
            if (e.range.getRow() == 3) {
            } else {
              var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
              html.value = old;
              ui.showModalDialog(html.evaluate().setHeight(100), '⚠️ Change order? ⚠️');
            }
          }
        }
      }

      function processForNo(old) {
        // do something
      }

      function processForYes(value) {
        // do something
      }
    ```
  - HTML & Javascript side is the same with above sample script.
- Although I cannot confirm your function name from your question, from `var old = e.oldValue` in your script, I thought that you might be using the OnEdit trigger of the simple trigger. If my understanding is correct, when you use above script, please use the installable OnEdit trigger. By this, when the cell is edited, `showModalDialog` works. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

### References:

- [Custom dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly you want.

Because **it doesn't ask for yes or no.** It just shows a timeout message. But I think it can be modified as per your requirement.

```
function showTimeoutAlert(header, message, time){

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(
    HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
      '<div>'+ message + '</div>' +
      '<script> \
  var a = document.querySelector("div"); \
  a.addEventListener("click",()=>{setTimeout(google.script.host.close,'+ time +')}); \
  a.click(); \
  </script>'
    ).setHeight(50),
    header
  );

}
```

Use it like:

```
showTimeoutAlert("No serial number(s) found", "Sr. No(s) 2, 3 not found", 2000)
```

It will show this message for 2 seconds
[image]

One can adjust timeout time in milliseconds.